# Download older versions of Google Chrome for Linux

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking for older versions of Google Chrome Stable. Now, older versions for Windows are available easily but I need it for Linux, preferably Debs not RPMs. As far as the versions are concerned, I am more specifically looking out for versions 17.0+. As in, versions older than 17 are also required but versions including 17 and after 17 are a must.

Where can I get Chrome's stable older versions?

**Note:** 
We need Chrome here not Chromium. Even though Chrome comes out of the Chromium project, but you can never be sure as to what additions/changes have been made to Chromium's code in Chrome. So what we need is Chrome, not Chromium.

Comment: You can find it here https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Comment: You can find older versions of Chrome here: ```http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_CHROME_VERSION_amd64.deb``` ( replace CHROME_VERSION with the version you are looking for, e.g. 77.0.3865.120-1)

Comment: For linux rpms ?

Comment: For RPMs: `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-CHROME_VERSION.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: Unfortunately these URLs now give 404s. Looks like Google is not allowing downloads of older stable versions for Linux.

Answer (score 25):

Here is the best mirror I have found so far for google-chrome-stable for RPM-based systems.

http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/google/

Comment: Update: it is no longer reachable

Answer (score 21):

Try searching google using the "inurl:" option to find an unofficial mirror:

**Google Prompt:** `inurl:/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/`

Mirrors pop up and go away from time to time--Not sure why, but nothing seems to stick with the 3rd party mirrors... Maybe it's a legal issue, or maybe it's just a ploy to get everyone to upgrade for better or for worse. It's kindof a pain, and I'm kicking myself now for cleaning up the /var/cache/apt/archives folder.

You can also google search specific known file names for the deb packages from the local package cache and get some hits for other mirrors with other files--The web download from Google gives you an installer without a version number in the file name, but the full file name shows up in the local apt cache. Using a random file name from the local apt cache will give you better results than copying and pasting an example name from a blog or from a known mirror with a limited version history.

Use the [Gentoo checksums](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/www-client/google-chrome/Manifest?hideattic=0&view=log) which pop up in the file name searches when obtaining the installers from untrusted sites or use the file names that the manifests provide to search for the version that you want.

Comment: Still useful to get those elusive versions of chrome

Answer (score 13):

You can get older versions of Chrome from http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php . They have cached old versions of Chrome for windows, linux and Mac.